# Shopify - Related products sometimes don't display

Tags: shopify, liquid

On my product.liquid I am pulling my related-products.liquid segment of code:

```
{% if collection and collection.products_count > 1 %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <h2 class="collection-title">Related products</h2>
  </div>
</div> 

<div class="row products">

{% assign current_product = product %}
{% assign current_product_found = false %}
{% for product in collection.products limit: 5 %}
  {% if product.handle == current_product.handle %}
    {% assign current_product_found = true %}
  {% else %}
    {% unless current_product_found == false and forloop.last %}
      {% include 'product-loop-shop' with collection.handle %}
    {% endunless %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

</div>

{% endif %}
```

When I first click on a product from my home page the related products display, and when I click on one of the related products the whole related products block at bottom does not appear.

If I'm leaving out something please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The `collection` variable is only set on the collection pages (pages using the `collection.liquid` template). Within the product pages (pages using the `product.liquid` template), it normally isn't set.

Nested product pages (`/collection/sale/product/my_product`) are the only exception where the `collection` variable is set within product pages (using the `product.liquid`).

So to solve your problem you can use two approaches:

- use the `within` [filter](http://wiki.shopify.com/Within) for all product urls inside the `product-loop-shop`, so the generated urls will always be nested within a collection
- display the related products using the `collections` [variable](http://wiki.shopify.com/Collections) (note the extra **s**), which is a general variable and thus always set